# How to reset the password for an HP iLO5 account via CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface, hp, ilo

I was scouring Google for a CLI command to reset the password of HPE iLO 5 accounts but didn't get any proper response.
UI solutions to reset the password or other tooling don't help me in this situation.

The [HPE iLO 5 Scripting and Command Line Guide](https://manualzz.com/doc/o/ugsvk/hpe-ilo-5-scripting-and-command-line-guide-smash-clp-scripting-language) leaves some questions open. HPE apparently created '**Base commands**'. In the 'User commands' section is an example to create a new account

```
create username=lname1 password=password
```

is it in this case possible to use `set` in order to change the password?

```
set username=lname1 password=password02!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cd` into the user to set its password.

```
</map1/accounts1/test>hpiLO-> set password=NewPassw0rd

status=0
status_tag=COMMAND COMPLETED
Tue Aug  9 12:44:05 2022

User information modified successfully.
```

Alternatively, provide the full path to the user:

```
set /map1/accounts1/test password=NewPassw0rd
```

---

Explanation:

> The general syntax of a CLP command is:
> `<verb>` `<target>` `<option>` `<property>`

and

> **Target** — The default target is the /. Change the target using the cd command, or by specifying a target on
> the command line.

- `set` is the verb.
- `/map1/accounts1/test` is the target. You don't need it if you `cd` into it beforehand.
- we don't need any options
- `password` is the property you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

If you forgot the password of the iLo, I think you need physical access to do the reset as well as the serial of the iLo on the tag on the actual server. You cant overwrite a lost password remotely, if that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi yield, no it's not about forgetting the password but periodically changing the password automatically. We use a PAM tool and need -- ideally -- a CLI command which will be run by the service every set interval.